# WP Cron, how to speed it up

Tags: wp-cron, cron

On my site, I have quite a few cron jobs running. Everything is running smoothly, except the cron jobs end up queuing all time.

My server load is only at 40%, so I assume I can handle more cron jobs simultaneously than I do now and thereby get rid of the queuing.

But how do I do that? i.e. is there a way to tell WP Cron that it can take on more jobs simultaneously than it does now?

Thanks,
Mads